# Coming back to the previous Activity State

Tags: android, android-layout, view, android-listview

I have an Activity named A,
in this, a ListView and one button are there.After clicking on this button,List View is shown and from this list view, by clicking on a its items, I can move to Activity B.

Now the problem is this when I come back from Activity B -> Activity A then, I see the Button only not the list view.

because I am calling intent of Activity A..

Code

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i;

            i = new Intent(B.this, A.class);

        startActivity(i);
        finish();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

In Activity B, I have the above implementation and i am using finish() in On Pause() condition also.

I want to see the List View with buttons.
Do i need to call whole code again to show the ListView or is there any other way to resolve this problem??
Is there any way to save the previous activity view?

Comment: You are finishing the activity A as you switch to Activity B. Just do not finish the Activity A. And checkout whether it works or not?

Comment: I think your have maintain one flag which is by default false and when click on button flag became true now check condition on onResume() if flag is true then list gone and flag set false again else list show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you are finishing `Activity A` before switching to `Activity B`. If you want your `ListView` as it is then do not finish `Activity A` and then try. If still your data does not visible then bind your listview again in `onResume()` of Activity A.

```
//removed finish().
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = new Intent(B.this, A.class);
    startActivity(i);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You are creating your activity aagain since u hv called the finish
>   method and when u go back it calls onCreate rather it should call
>   onResume method of lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

Just do one thing.rmove finish() from your code

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i;

        i = new Intent(B.this, A.class);

    startActivity(i);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

onResume called when activity start or when you return from another activity as per life cycle of Activity, its better to keep your code inside onResume, which will refill your listview with data.

***SO when you called activity B from A (in Activity A fill your listview inside onResume method) and when you press back, its again callon onResume and fill your listview.***

> Instead# doing code inside onBackPressed of activity B.